# Is there a predefined function to get all original size images in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, media, media-library

I figured out that wordpress doesn't save the images or the links to the images of the media library in the database. Only attached images of posts or pages will be saved. Is there a predefined function to get all (original size) images of the media library?

I didn't find anything yet. I would know how to write an own recursive function with a lot of regex statements that parses through the uploads folder of the wordpress directory and transforms the paths to links but I would prefer if there is a predefined one. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're understanding the meaning of "attachment." That's the post type you'll need to query for the images. For example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status'    => 'inherit', 
    'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$wp_images = new WP_Query( $args );

$images = array();
foreach ( $wp_images->posts as $image ) {
    // Add each image src to the $images array
    $images[]= wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
}
```

Comment: Thx, but I already tried something like that. It only returns images that are attached to a post or a page. But uploaded images that doesn't belong to any page or post will not be showed.